# R package installation issue: "no permission to install to directory"

Tags: r

I'm having a problem when I try to install the package "BMR" from Github. I receive a warning telling me something like:

> "Erro: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Users/higor/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
>   Error: Failed to install 'BMR' from GitHub:
>     (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/higor/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpURE5wz/file1648705674f9/BMR_0.11.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the package with admin privilege: on Windows, right click on your R shortcut, select "run as administrator", then install your package. The package will then be installed in the root R library (not sure where that would be on Windows) instead of being installed in your personal R library.

After this, you can launch R the way you normally do and you should be able to load and use the package.

Another solution is to change the mode of your R library directory (`C:/Users/higor/Documents/R/win-library/3.6`).

Comment: How would i do that second solution? I've never seen something like that before...

Comment: I am not sure what the easiest way to do this is on Windows (I use Linux)

Comment: The first solution is the simplest and the one I suggest you try though